# openCL clGetDeviceIds seg fault (imx6 (Freescale) with openCL on a Linux SUSE distribution (armv7))

Tags: opencl, embedded-linux, suse

I'm developing an application with openCL on an imx6q (freescale - Vivante gc200 with openCL EP) with a Linux suse 13.1 distribution adapted for armv7.

I'm based on the following tutorial : https://community.freescale.com/docs/DOC-93984#comment-12585. I installed the following package : gpu-viv-bin-mx6q.

When I try the example code, it works on a laptop version, but on the imx6, it gives me a segmentation fault when calling the function clGetDeviceIds.

The program is compiled correctly but not work when running;

I tried by passing different null variables in the function. I'm not sure if it's due to memory allocation (as the same code work on my laptop, i can suppose this is not the problem). When I launch it in debug mode, the program seems not to find the file : "gc_hal_user_query.c" (hal is for Hardware Abstraction Layer).

I can't find sufficient documentation on the web, and i'm quite newbie on linux and openCL, so if anybody could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I ran into the same issue, with a little different setup, did you solve the problem?

Comment: I get the same issue. Gdb tells me the error is in gcoHAL_QuerySeparated3D2D inside gc_hal_user_query.c, which indicates that it is a driver problem. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that, when you call

```
clGetPlatformIDs(1, &cpPlatform, NULL);
```

cpPlatform receives 0 if no platform is detected. This leads to a segmentation fault during the next call to

```
clGetDeviceIDs(cpPlatform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &cdDevice, NULL);
```

I unfortunately can't help further, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are running with insufficient permissions. Try running as root.